# How to not add sequence to the same group pandas based on date time

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
id   date               day
A    01/01/2023 00:00   01
A    01/01/2023 00:00   01
B    01/01/2023 01:00   01
B    01/01/2023 01:00   01
A    01/01/2023 02:00   01
A    02/01/2023 00:00   02
```

The output I expect is

```
id   date               day  count
A    01/01/2023 00:00   01   1   
A    01/01/2023 00:00   01   1   (2 rows are 1 because they fall under same group)
B    01/01/2023 01:00   01   1   (this is 1 because ID is different)
B    01/01/2023 01:00   01   1
A    01/01/2023 02:00   01   2   (this is incremented because it happened on same day)
A    02/01/2023 00:00   02   1  (this is 1 because the day has changed)
```

Grouping is done on ID, date, day and you can assume the dataframe is sorted by id and date.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
df['count']  = df.groupby(['id','day'])['date'].rank('dense').astype(int)
```